# Why does my script output an end &bull; ( • ) and what is the best way to remove it?

Tags: php, variables, output, isset

I wrote this "You are here" script for a website and it is working, however the output for the story category has an extra trailing bull and I'd like to know why and remove the •

```
<?php
if (isset($_GET['pagina']) && isset($_GET['storycategory'])) {
$pagina = $_GET['pagina'];
$storycategory = $_GET['storycategory'];
$storypage = $storycategory;
$storypage = str_replace(stories, story, $storypage);
$storypagename = $_GET[$storypage];
$content_path = 'You are here: Home &bull; ' . $pagina . ' &bull; ' . $storycategory . ' &bull; ' . $storypagename;
$content_path = str_replace("-", " ", $content_path);
echo '<strong>' . $content_path . '</strong><hr />'; // Voor een bezoeker die in een bepaald verhaal bezoekt - Output: You are here: Home • all stories • story category Name • Best story ever
}
elseif (isset($_GET['pagina']) && isset($_GET['storycategory'])) { // this is the part that has a trailing  •  that I'd like to remove and find out why it was created by my script
    $pagina = $_GET['pagina'];
    $storycategory = $_GET['storycategory'];
    $content_path = 'You are here: Home &bull; ' . $pagina . ' &bull; ' . $storycategory; // Note: I did NOT add a  •  here but it is generated in output...
    $content_path = str_replace("-", " ", $content_path);
    echo '<strong>' . $content_path . '</strong><hr />'; // Voor een bezoeker die in een bepaalde alles uit deze story category pagina is! Output: You are here: Home You are here: Home • all stories • story category Name • 
    }
    elseif (isset($_GET['pagina'])) {
        $pagina = $_GET['pagina'];
        $content_path = 'You are here: Home &bull; ' . $pagina;
        $content_path = str_replace("-", " ", $content_path);
        echo '<strong>' . $content_path . '</strong><hr />'; // Voor een bezoeker die op de alle sex stories pagina is! Output: Home • all stories
        }
        else {
            // Als iemand verdwaald is en daardoor bovenstaande totaal niet van toepassing is...
            echo '<strong>Thank you for visiting our site!</strong><hr />';
            }
            ?>
```

Pagina is just fine, no trailing bull but when I visit any category there will be a  •  that I don't like to show up (See comment output and note in the code) but when I visit any story page in any category there is no  •  at the end...

How should I remove the bull and why was it generated?

Thank you for reading!

**EDIT**
I would like to explain the used variables in my code, I hope it will help to understand this question.

I have some URL's and would like to tell visitors where they are:

Page for a story:    www.example.com/index.php?pagina=all-stories&storycategory=the-best-stories&the-best-story=my-first-computer

Page for all stories inside "the best stories":  www.example.com/index.php?pagina=all-stories&storycategory=the-best-stories

Page for all story categories:  www.example.com/index.php?pagina=all-stories

I have a folder called pagina, in this folder you will find a folder called storycategory, in the folder storycategory you will find a huge number of folders and all of them have stories as last part of their names and a lot of php files that have story at the end of there mame (same names but changed stories to story for the php files in storycategory) in the folders inside storycategory folder are my stories stored..

Part 1 to echo "you are here: Home • all stories • the best story • my first computer" this is working just fine

```
        if (isset($_GET['pagina']) && isset($_GET['storycategory']) && isset($_GET['storycategory'])) {
$pagina = $_GET['pagina'];
$storycategory = $_GET['storycategory'];
$storypage = $storycategory;
$storypage = str_replace(stories, story, $storypage);
$storypagename = $_GET[$storypage];
$content_path = 'You are here: Home &bull; ' . $pagina . ' &bull; ' . $storycategory . ' &bull; ' . $storypagename;
$content_path = str_replace("-", " ", $content_path);
echo '<strong>' . $content_path . '</strong><hr />'; // Voor een bezoeker die in een bepaald verhaal bezoekt - Output: You are here: Home • all stories • story category Name • Best story ever
}
```

Part 2 where it's going wrong with the unwanted •

```
    elseif (isset($_GET['pagina']) && isset($_GET['storycategory'])) { // this is the part that has a trailing  •  that I'd like to remove and find out why it was created by my script
$pagina = $_GET['pagina'];
$storycategory = $_GET['storycategory'];
$content_path = 'You are here: Home &bull; ' . $pagina . ' &bull; ' . $storycategory; // Note: I did NOT add a  •  here but it is generated in output...
$content_path = str_replace("-", " ", $content_path);
echo '<strong>' . $content_path . '</strong><hr />'; // Voor een bezoeker die in een bepaalde alles uit deze story category pagina is! Output: You are here: Home You are here: Home • all stories • story category Name • 
}
```

Part 3 that is just fine too, without problems

```
    elseif (isset($_GET['pagina'])) {
    $pagina = $_GET['pagina'];
    $content_path = 'You are here: Home &bull; ' . $pagina;
    $content_path = str_replace("-", " ", $content_path);
    echo '<strong>' . $content_path . '</strong><hr />'; // Voor een bezoeker die op de alle sex stories pagina is! Output: Home • all stories
    }
```

Part 4 of my code is the else for if no story related variable was set or unknown error

```
    else {
        // Als iemand verdwaald is en daardoor bovenstaande totaal niet van toepassing is...
        echo '<strong>Thank you for visiting our site!</strong><hr />';
        }
```

What is wrong with part 2 or why do I get the bull at the end?

**EDIT 2**
edited line 2
Replaced 
if (isset($_GET['pagina']) && isset($_GET['storycategory']) && isset($_GET['storycategory'])) {
with
if (isset($_GET['pagina']) && isset($_GET['storycategory'])) {

Problem with  • at the end is still there on the storycategory pages,   `$storypage` is used to create `$storypagename` from `storycategory` using str_replace and Home is hard coded.

**EDIT 3** (Solved)
`isset($_GET[$storypagename]))` (Line 2) and `$storypagename = $_GET[$storypagename];` did solve the problem in the srories global file, but any variable must be defined before a request like I said in comments before so I had to find a way to define `$storypagename` **before** line 2. I defined it in all of the meta tag files for every single page and this is working perfect.

**NOTE**: The last 2 bold parts **are** dynamic, so the last url variable will change if a visitor is in any other category. 
**Story page:** www.example.com/index.php?pagina=all-stories&storycategory=the-best-stories&**the-best-story**=**my-first-computer** 
**Page for stories inthis category:** www.example.com/index.php?pagina=all-stories&storycategory=the-best-stories
**Page for all story categories:** www.example.com/index.php?pagina=all-stories

First I tried to use str_replace() using the storycategory value but I was not able to define it before so it never worked, I believe a small extra line in meta tag file `$storypagename = 'the-best-story';` is the best available solution

My site has a 1000's of pages so an `array()` was no option, every page has got a meta tag php file and is loaded before this script, there I defined the `$storypagename` variable to make sure it will be defined before it will be requested. this solution made php code smaller.

I'd like to say thank you to both **mudasobwa** AND **Konstantin**, both answers were helpful to find this method to solve this error.
All 3 parts are working fine now, thanks again!
**Final working code**

```
    <?php 
    if (isset($_GET['pagina']) && isset($_GET['storycategory']) && isset($_GET[$storypagename])) {
    $pagina = $_GET['pagina'];
    $storycategory = $_GET['storycategory'];
    $storypagename = $_GET[$storypagename];
    $content_path = 'You are here: Home &bull; ' . $pagina . ' &bull; ' . $storycategory . ' &bull; ' . $storypagename;
    $content_path = str_replace("-", " ", $content_path);
    echo '<strong>' . $content_path . '</strong><hr />'; // Voor een bezoeker die in een bepaald verhaal bezoekt - Output: You are here: Home • all stories • story category Name • Best story ever
    }
    elseif (isset($_GET['pagina']) && isset($_GET['storycategory'])) { // this is the part that has a trailing  •  that I'd like to remove and find out why it was created by my script
$pagina = $_GET['pagina'];
$storycategory = $_GET['storycategory'];
$content_path = 'You are here: Home &bull; ' . $pagina . ' &bull; ' . $storycategory;  // Note: I did NOT add a  •  here but it is generated in output...
$content_path = str_replace("-", " ", $content_path);
echo '<strong>' . $content_path . '</strong><hr />'; // Voor een bezoeker die in een bepaalde alles uit deze story category pagina is! Output: You are here: Home You are here: Home • all stories • story category Name • 
}
    elseif (isset($_GET['pagina'])) {
    $pagina = $_GET['pagina'];
    $content_path = 'You are here: Home &bull; ' . $pagina;
    $content_path = str_replace("-", " ", $content_path);
    echo '<strong>' . $content_path . '</strong><hr />'; // Voor een bezoeker die op de alle sex stories pagina is! Output: Home • all stories
    }
    else {
        // Als iemand verdwaald is en daardoor bovenstaande totaal niet van toepassing is...
        echo '<strong>Thank you for visiting our site!</strong><hr />';
               }
               ?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You copy-pasted the very first `if` condition erroneously:

```
if (
  isset($_GET['pagina']) && 
  isset($_GET['storycategory']) && 
  isset($_GET['storycategory'])) { // ERROR, should be $_GET['storypagename']
```

and you enter this with empty `$storypagename`.

Whether `$storypagename` is being calculated, it should be calculated and checked here, because this condition is likely always `true` and you never enter `else if` sections.

Comment: Yes, I understand, that should be but at the beginning of my code storypagename doesn't exist so I should define it first or don't check $storypagename (it is defined on line 7 so cannot use it on line 2), I'll try to define it before line 2, I think that would be better, otherwise it will return an error if I change it.. I can post my link to the story pages but not sure it's allowed to post an adult story URL.. first part and last part are working. the only problem is  • at the end of part 2

Comment: It is **Part 1**, not Part 2. Your code never reaches Part 2.

Answer (score 0):

As mudasobwa said: because of the error in your first condition (on line 2)

```
if (isset($_GET['pagina']) && isset($_GET['storycategory']) && isset($_GET['storycategory'])) {
```

you never enter the first `elseif` block (at line 12)

the line that gets executed is line 8:

```
$content_path = 'You are here: Home &bull; ' . $pagina . ' &bull; ' . $storycategory . ' &bull; ' . $storypagename;
```

but the `$storypagename` is empty. so you end up with a bullet at the end

Comment: I edited my post to explain my code, the `$storypagename` is created on line 7, this is the first part and the first part is working, I can add a link to my site but I'm not sure if I can post it here, all stories are for adults only... however if I post the link you'll be able to see what is working, thank you for your answer but it didn't solve my problem however I found duplicated code on line 2 and removed it, thanks again for pointing me to line 2!

Comment: Both of the answers were helpful to me, your answer is more detailed, it did help me to write final code available in **EDIT 3** last `storycategory` has been changed to `$storypagename` and I needed to define it in every meta tag file for every page, so I still need to write 500 lines for the last 500 pages, thank you for answering this question, I accept your answer, it solved half of the problem, thanks again!